# Is RedHat directory server free if you have a Redhat license (RHEL 5)?

Tags: redhat, ldap, 389-ds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

If I have a RHEL 5 server with a paid subscription do I need to purchase any licenses / keys to run  Redhat Directory server on the box ?

Thanks 
Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RedHat Directory Server is an additional entitlement you need to purchase.  You can use the RedHat-packaged OpenLDAP server freely, but their Directory server is an additional license that must be purchased.

There are sales contact links off of this page http://www.redhat.com/directory_server/

We have a site license for RedHat, and had contacted them a few months ago about adding Directory Server.  I am positive it is an additional fee.

Comment: can you link this as i couldnt locate it anywhere on my search of the red hat site

Comment: found it: http://www.redhat.com/directory_server/

Comment: Ok, people are indicating its not free with the OS , so can I used 389 directory server on RHEL for free is openldap the only free option ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but I have used the free Fedora Directory Server with CentOS systems, so that is an option if the RHEL offering requires a license.

http://directory.fedoraproject.org